# Remote end up unexpectedly while deploying Python on azure web app

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to deploy python Flask with spacy, downloading from requirements.text is fine however I am **repeatedly** getting this error. **Removing spacy the api is working fine**.

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
To https://abc.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/abc.git
```

[image]

Tried with VS Code->right click->Deploy to Web App . . . and **repeatedly** I am getting stuck on below screenshot for like and hour so I stopped web app from portal

[image]

Tried to see on antenv folder from Kudu and I get this

[image]

I am not sure here I have misconfigured anything wrong here. I guess the *error in sideband demultiplexer* is due to some python script rather than git. Any help would be appreciated